# Python Word Unscrambler: Code not permuting through entire list, but permutes individual list items

Tags: python, list, permutation

I am new to Python and am trying to unscramble words for the challenge on HackThisSite. I have a scrambled_list and a wordlist.

My goal with this code is to run permutations of the scrambled words and store them in a list called 'perms'. I then want to see if any of the permutations exist in the normal wordlist called 'myWords.' If so, they will be appended to the 'Solutions' list.

My issue is, the code works correctly for individual list items (e.g., sWords[0], or sWords[2]), but it won't permute through the entire list in one go.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import string 
from itertools import permutations

os.chdir('C:\Users\goodmat\Documents\Programming Challenges')

s = open('scrambled_list.txt', 'r')
w = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')

myWords = []
sWords = []
solutions = []

with w as f:
    myWords = [line.strip() for line in f]
with s as g:
    sWords = [line.strip() for line in g]


def permute():
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(sWords)]
    for each in perms:
        if each in myWords:
            solutions.append(each)

permute()
print solutions
```

Comment: `permutations(sWords)` !== `permutations(sWords[0])`  You are generating permutations of a list, not a word

Comment: You probably want something like `[''.join(p) for s in sWords for p in permutations(s)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are generating permutations of a list, not permutations of words within the list.

Instead generate permutations of individual words in your list:

```
scrambled = ['windwo', 'droo', 'phonehead', 'asdfjl']
word_list = ['window', 'door', 'car', 'headphone']

solutions = []
perms = [''.join(p) for s in scrambled for p in set(permutations(s))]

final = [each for each in perms if each in word_list]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['window', 'door', 'headphone']
```

Comment: That solved it, and the explanation was helpful. Thank you so much!